# Can we validate @RequestParam value with a pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i have a requirement, where in i need to validate my `@RequestParam` such that it is matched with my pattern

Example :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/someTest")
  public Object sendWishes(@RequestParam("birthDate") String birthDate)

    {
      // i need birthDate to be a valid date format in YYYYMMDD format
      // if its not valid it should not hit this method
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InitBinder will serve purpose. You Should have following init binding code in your controller:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDD");

    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

after that you can get birthDate in your specified YYYYMMDD as date object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someTest")
public Object sendWishes(@RequestParam("birthDate") Date birthDate)
```

Answer (score 9):

It should be very easy:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/someTest?birthDate={birthDate}")
  public Object sendWishes(@Valid @Pattern(regexp = "you-pattern-here") @RequestParam("birthDate") String birthDate)

  {
      // i need birthDate to be a valid date format in YYYYMMDD format
      // if its not valid it should not hit this method
  }
```

Comment: The @Valid annotation is part of the standard JSR-303 Bean Validation API - this doesn't work in this case. ...now if it was a bean...

Answer (score 3):

use @DateTimeFormat

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someTest")
public Object sendWishes(@RequestParam("birthDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="YYYYMMDD") LocalDate birthDate){ //Your code goes here }
```